# Can not run new game using cocos2d-x 3.3 for iOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm using cocos2d-x 3.3 and Xcode 6.1.1 to create a new game project. I have installed python already and run command on terminal to create Helloworld game project. It's look like:

```
$ cocos new Helloworld -p com.datnt.games -l cpp -d /Users/datnguyen/Desktop/DatNguyen/Games
```

And the result in terminal:

```
Running command: new
> Copy template into /Users/datnguyen/Desktop/DatNguyen/Games/Helloworld
> Copying cocos2d-x files...
> Rename project name from 'HelloCpp' to 'Helloworld'
> Replace the project name from 'HelloCpp' to 'Helloworld'
> Replace the project package name from 'org.cocos2dx.hellocpp' to 'com.datnt.games'
> Replace the mac bundle id from 'org.cocos2dx.hellocpp' to 'com.datnt.games'
> Replace the ios bundle id from 'org.cocos2dx.hellocpp' to 'com.datnt.games'
```

When I ran Xcode, I got the problem: project name was still HelloCpp and I can run game on simulator. I installed and created first game following the tutorial but I don't know  why the problem occurs. Can you please help me to resolve this problem?

My Xcode screen:
[image]

**UPDATE:** I can run this game perfectly using command in terminal: cocos run -p ios, but can not run using Xcode

Comment: So the problem is the program name is HelloCpp rather than Helloworld?  Or that you *can't* (typo in your question?) run the game on the simulator?

Comment: Yes, I can't run game on the simulator. I have not installed simulator 7.1 yet, I don't know what is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should right click your "HelloWorld.xcodeproj" file and choose "Show package contents".

And then you should delete both "project.xcworkspace" file and "xcuserdata" folder.(Only the project.pbxproj file is needed).

After that, try to reopen your Xcode project and see whether it is working or not.

Comment: @DatNguyen You should do it in Finder.

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal and get Desktop. $ cd Desktop
$ cocos new ProjectNM -p com.packageNM.ProjectNM -l cpp

Note: ->ProjectNM both side same as.

Ex. $ cocos new MyNewProject -p com.packageNM.MyNewProject -l cpp

simply-Go ProjectFolder/proj.ios_mac/MyNewProject.xcodeproj open it and select device and run.

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal and get Desktop.
$ cd Desktop

$ cocos new ProjectName -p com.packageName.ProjectName -l cpp

Note:
->ProjectName both side same as.

Ex.
$ cocos new MyNewProject -p com.packageName.MyNewProject -l cpp

simply-Go ProjectFolder/proj.ios_mac/MyNewProject.xcodeproj
open it and select device and run.